# Vert.x: Verticle custom startFuture handler is always rewritten

Tags: vert.x, vertx-verticle

Vert.x v3.5.1. 
There is my custom `start` method of Verticle:

```
@Override
public void start(Future<Void> startFuture) throws Exception {
    startFuture.setHandler(event -> {
        if (event.succeeded()) {
            logger.info("Server started on port: {}", 8080);
        } else {
            logger.warn("Failed to start: {}", event.cause());
        }
    });
    vertx.createHttpServer()
            .requestHandler(router()::accept)
            .listen(8080, event -> {
                if (event.succeeded()) {
                    startFuture.complete();
                } else {
                    startFuture.fail(event.cause());
                }
            });
}
```

I expect that my custom handler will be invoked when future completes. But it doesn't! 
In debug mode I see that `FutureImpl::setHandler` is called twice: once with my custom handler, and then with `DeploymentManager`'s handler during `doDeploy`. 
So the latest handler is applied.

The question is: is it possible to specify custom callback for Verticle start? If yes how can I do it?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not supposed to change the handler of the startFuture, as it is owned by the caller. So simply, don't do that :) The future is used to signal that you're done with your start-code, and not to define what should be done, once you're done.

In your concrete example it'd be better to write the logs once the http server came up, and then indicate to the startFuture, that you're done with your code execution.

```
@Override
public void start(Future<Void> startFuture) throws Exception {
    vertx.createHttpServer()
         .requestHandler(router()::accept)
         .listen(8080, event -> {
            if (event.succeeded()) {
                logger.info("Server started on port: {}", 8080);
                startFuture.complete();
            } else {
                logger.warn("Failed to start: {}", event.cause());
                startFuture.fail(event.cause());
            }
         });
}
```

Comment: Okey, just not obvious Future interface. It has setHandler method that actually cannot be used by childs.

Comment: It's more obvious from the documentation of `start(future)` on the Verticle interface: `A future is passed into the method, and when deployment is complete the verticle should either call complete or fail the future.` You could, however, create your own future, set it's handler to complete the startFuture, and call your own future once the http server is up. I often use this pattern with CompositeFuture, when I have multiple async tasks during startup

Answer (score 0):

At first, write your verticle as a AbstractVerticle extension. And do not override `start(Future)` method. Instead use `start()` method. It will be called from `AbstractVerticle.start(Future)`, and you can specify that future in `Vertx.deployVerticle(verticle, options, future)` method.

For example:

You have some verticle. Do in it `start()` method only initialization tasks:

```
@Override
public void start() throws Exception {
    vertx.eventbus().consume(address, m -> {
       // consumer code skipped
    });
}
```

and verticle registration:

```
final DeploymentOptions opts = new DeploymentOptions().setWorker(true);
vertx.deployVerticle(verticle, opts, event -> {
    if (event.succeeded()) {
        log.info("Verticle successfully deployed. DeploymentId: " + event.result());
    } else {
        log.error("Verticle failed to deploy. Cause: " + event.cause().getMessage(), event.cause());
    }
});
```

That's all :)

Comment: Ok, actually I don't see the relations between using of completionHandler in deploy method and using of AbstractVerticle class. But seems I can use this completionHandler for my purposes, thanks!

Comment: @katrin glad to help you, Kat